# Error encountered while loading Microsoft Translation provider

Tags: visual-studio, localization, visual-studio-extensions

I have Visual Studio 2022 with the Multilingual App Toolkit v4.2.3 (VS 2022+) plugin installed.

I configure the Microsoft Translator in settings with a valid Azure Translator subscription key and region (southcentralus). After I click OK and reopen settings the region is not set and the key will blank if I restart Visual Studio.

[image: MAT configuration]

If I try to use the translator I get this error message:

> An error was encountered while loading the Microsoft Translation provider. Go to Tools -> Options -> Multilingual App Toolkit to configure it.

[image: MAT error]

[image: MAT console error]

What am I missing. We have tried reinstalling the extension and clearing the credentials in Windows Credential Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and what fixed it for me was to open the Multilingual Editor app and add the credentials in the [settings menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTBlL.png). The changes carried over to Visual Studio.

I'm using Version 4.1.13.0 of the Multilingual Editor app.

Answer (score 1):

What is the version of your visual Studio? I installed Multilingual App Toolkit v4.2.3 on VS2022 17.7.4 and the Subscription key and region were set normally.

From looking at the error message, it seems like that the package could not find credentials. For this issue, please check the following:

1.Please check if you have enabled selection.
[image]
2.Please uninstall this extension and update it to the latest version.

3.Please check if you have created a Translator resource in your Azure subscription and obtained the subscription key and the API endpoint.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/Translator/quickstart-text-rest-api?tabs=csharp

4.Please test it in postman and check if you are able to invoke Azure AI Translator REST APIs successfully.

5.Check if your Translator resource is in the Global region and recreate a new.

6.Please configure the settings in another visual stuio instance and see if the issue persists.

7.Make sure you have the latest service pack and critical updates for the versions of Windows and Visual Studio that you are running. To find
recent security updates, use Windows Update.

If the suggestions above do not help, please try to repair/update  your visual studio.

Comment: Thank you. We didn't have any success with the steps above. What work was we discovered settings were added to a newer version of the multilingual editor. Setting the connection from there has solved the problem. Setting from VS still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by setting the settings in the Multilingual Editor instead of with the Visual Studio extension.

[image: Editor settings]

Be sure you have a version that of the MAT editor that has the settings in it. Older versions do not have this ability.

Not being able to set the configuration from the Visual Studio plugin does appear to be a bug: https://github.com/microsoft/Multilingual-App-Toolkit/issues/14